# How to add arrow annotations?

Tags: dm-script

I need to add a batch of arrow annotations to an image, I know all the start and end points of the arrows.
And I've put them into an image (2 columns, many rows) which I used as a data sheet, how to realize it in script?

I noticed that in the *DM help manual* that the line annotation has the attributes-- start point and end point.
But the function to create an arrow annotation jsut looks like this:
`Component NewArrowAnnotation( Number top, Number left, Number bottom, Number right )`

Does that mean the number `top` and `left` define the start point, number `bottom` and `right` the end point?

I also need to change the color of the annotations, and add some text next to them (either side is OK, but please show me how to control it).

Answer (score 0):

What isn't always clear from the current documentation is that *annotations* belong to the *component* object. You therefore find all required commands documented in the *component section* of the help documentation.

[image: Comp Help]

Note that also *imageDisplays* are themselves a subclass of the *component* object, so you can add "annotations" (components) to "imageDisplay" (components) using the `ComponentAddChild...` commands.

A script to add a simple arrow-annotation (pointing at 200/200) can therefore look like the following:

```
image test := RealImage( "Test", 4, 512, 512 )
test.ShowImage()
ImageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

component arrow = NewArrowAnnotation(100,100,200,200)
arrow.ComponentSetForegroundColor( 0, 1, 1 )
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( arrow )
```

[image: Result]